# Reduce queue time for SFMC API requests

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

When using the Salesforce Marketing Cloud (SFMC) SOAP API, e.g. to run a Query Activity, we notice a `task` gets created. The task initially has a `Status: Queued` until `Complete`. This queue time can be significant. Also, it seems that when we repeat a certain call a few times (e.g. during testing), the queue time increases.

We are looking for a way to reduce this queue time. In the docs I found a bit about [priority](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/priority_appex.htm?search_text=priority).

My questions:

1. Is this something that can be used for all SOAP calls? If so, how?
2. If not, is there another way?

Regarding point 1, it might be possible it's only relevant for triggered sends, since a Google search returns results where it is mostly described in such a context, like [here](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000sx2QQAQ).

Here I tried to use `priority` which resulted in an error:

```
<soapenv:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<PerformRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
<Action>Start</Action>
<Definitions>
<ns1:Definition xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xsi:type="ns1:QueryDefinition">
<ns1:PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns1:ModifiedDate xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns1:ObjectID>IDHIDDEN</ns1:ObjectID>
<ns1:Priority>High</ns1:Priority>
</ns1:Definition>
</Definitions>
</PerformRequestMsg>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Here I tried `priority` which did not seem to make a difference (the call worked as before):

```
<soapenv:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<PerformRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
<Action>Start</Action>
<Priority>High</Priority>
<Definitions>
<ns1:Definition xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xsi:type="ns1:QueryDefinition">
<ns1:PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns1:ModifiedDate xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns1:ObjectID>IDHIDDEN</ns1:ObjectID>
</ns1:Definition>
</Definitions>
</PerformRequestMsg>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Comment: Please also note that increasing priority level is still dependent on the current queue and volume inside the MTA, so the effectiveness can vary.  Also, Higher priority on triggered sends will increase the cost per email.

Comment: @Gortonington thank you for your answer. Yes, I assumed something like that would be the case.

We mostly need higher priority on Query Activities. Could you tell me what our SOAP call look like and how do I know if it was effective?